# jquery disable autocomplete plugin not working in IE 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

The plugin mentioned in the below github url not working properly on IE 11.

https://github.com/say2joe/jquery.disable-autocomplete

When password input is given , it is send as "dsfjhdsjfspassword". A "password" string is appended to the end of password input.

I tried the same plugin in chrome, firefox, IE 8 and IE 9. It works well on these browsers.

Comment: When you say "it is sent as...", where are you seeing this and how are you sending it? (Is it in a form that you're submitting normally or are you using Ajax...?) Also, try looking at the html in your browser's developer tools. The plugin creates a hidden field for replacing the password field. If the behavior that you're seeing comes from the plugin, the value of that input should already contain the "password" string.